# Bash: Recursively loop through folder and subfolders and inject HTML files

Tags: bash, sed

I need a way to inject some HTML after the body tag in any HTML documents present in a folder or it's subfolders. I found this in another thread, but I'm unsure of the sed part:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "*.html" | while read FILE; do
    sed -i '.bak' '/{{endSTRING}}/r htmlHeader
    /{{startSTRING}}/,/{{endSTRING}}/d' ${FILE}
done
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: If you're happy that the `find` part of the loop works, it'd be more useful to focus on a specific example of a file that you're trying to perform a substitution on. That said, `sed` is totally the wrong tool for the job; you're much better off using a tool that understands HTML rather than one that just treats it as lines of plain text.

Comment: @TomFenech Okay thanks. I was looking for a quick fix that didn't involve DOM parsing, will go back and look into that.